# Failover connection URL with SSL/TLS from Qpid JMS

Tags: ssl, qpid

**I attempt to connect to a RabbitMQ cluster (AMQP 1.0 plugin enabled) with a Qpid JMS 0.48.0 client and with SSL enabled, using a failover URI.**

This does not work:

```
failover:(amqps://host1:5671?transport.verifyHost=false,amqps://host2:5671?transport.verifyHost=false,amqps://host3:5671?transport.verifyHost=false)
```

But this works (without SSL):

```
failover:(amqp://host1:5672,amqp://host2:5672,amqp://host3:5672)
```

SSL is well configured, as this works:

```
amqps://host1:5671?transport.verifyHost=false
```

No error message on standard output, no logs.

I get exactly the same behavior when connecting to an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster.

Also, I have no problem using multiple URIs with SSL from a Qpid Proton client in Python:

```
server_addr = ['amqps://host1:5671', 'amqps://host2:5671', 'amqps://host3:5671']
```

Can you please tell me what's going on?

Comment: You need to configure logging using the framework you've chosen to include and collect trace logs

Answer (score 0):

Testing the client with an different AMQP server implementation shows no issue with the client enabling or disabling the verify host option with or without failover in the mix.  You should enable client logging using something like log4j on the path and collect data around the connect disconnect cycle and determine why it fails with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect like this:

```
failover:amqps://host1:5671,amqps://host2:5671?transport.verifyHost=false
```